# Intent putExtra with array of object implementing Parcelable

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, parcelable, badparcelableexception

I want to add an array of instances of `Person` class, this class implements `Parcelable`. I tried the code below

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, new Intent().putExtra("persons", persons));
finish();
```

to store the array in an intent from the sender activity, and the next code in the reciever activity to retrieve it

```
if(requestCode == PERSON_REQUEST_CODE && resultcode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    persons = (Person[]) data.getParcelableArrayExtra("persons"); // persons is Person[]
```

however, I'm getting an error when running it

```
07-26 06:29:59.560: E/AndroidRuntime(632): Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called  CREATOR on class Person
```

Is it not running because I'm casting the array to `Person[]`?

EDIT

Here is my `Person` class

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Person implements Parcelable {
    private String fname;
    private String lname;

    public Person() {}

    Person(Parcel in) {
        this.fname = in.readString();
        this.lname = in.readString();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String fname) { this.fname = fname; }
    public void setLastName(String lname)  { this.lname = lname; }

    public String getFirstName() { return fname; }
    public String getLastName()  { return lname; }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(fname);
        dest.writeString(lname);
    }

    static final Parcelable.Creator<Person> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Person>() {
        @Override
        public Person[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Person[size];
        }

        @Override
        public Person createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Person(source);
        }
    };
}
```

EDIT #2

I was able to solve it by writing the following code

```
Parcelable[] parcelablePersons = data.getParcelableArrayExtra("persons");
persons = new Person[parcelablePersons.length];
for(int i = 0; i < parcelablePersons.length; i++) {
    persons[i] = (Person) parcelablePersons[i];
}
```

Comment: post your Person class

Comment: I added my `Person` class

Comment: you don't nedd `(Person[])` in `(Person[]) data.getParcelableArrayExtra("persons");`

Comment: `persons` is `Person[]`

Comment: Try that: `data.getExtras().getParcelableArray("persons");`

Comment: I tried the above code but I had to cast it to `Person[]` but I am getting `ClassCastException`

Comment: I got it to work by storing `data.getParcelableArrayExtra("persons")` in a `Parcelable[]` and then looping over every element and casting it to `Person` and storing it in `persons` variable

Comment: instead of the loop in EDIT #2 you could:
Parcelable[] parcelablePersons = data.getParcelableArrayExtra("persons");
Person[] integerArray = Arrays.copyOf(parcelablePersons, parcelablePersons.length, Person[].class);

Answer (score 3):

Your `CREATOR` instance must be public. Currently it's package private.